# New to MacOS, need a automator that can copy cells from Google Sheets to fill up form in Safari/Chrom

Tags: macos, safari, automator, google-chrome, copy-paste

I am new to MacOS, have been using Windows all my life
I normally use AHK (Auto HotKey)to copy cells from Google Sheets, and automatically fill in a web form and press generate.
Normally I assign the copy of cells to F1 key and the F2 key to paste each cell data while doing [tab] to go next field.

I'll break down in screenshots below....

[image]

[image]

[image]

It will be amazing if someone has an alternative or a more efficient method on Mac

Thank you for your time